# Ajax url is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm making a function to get a xml file and edit it. I've never done that before so I searched a good way to get an xml file. I decided to use ajax, but the file is never returned because the url is undefined.

EDIT : 
I edited the code and made the treatment in the success function. Now there is no problem with this file.
Here is the update of the ajax part :

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'allrtp.xml',
    dataType: 'xml',
    success: function(xml) {
        //file = $.parseXML(xml);

        // Editing the file to have the good dates
        $(xml).find('StartDateTime').text(start);
        $(xml).find('EndDateTime').text(end);

        var strFile;

        if (window.ActiveXObject) {
            strFile = xml.xml;
        } else {
            strFile = (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(xml);
        }

        var encoded64 = Base64.encode(strFile); // Encoded in base64
        var encodeURL = encodeURIComponent(encoded64); // Encoded URL

        var AR = urlAR + encodeURL; // The URL to open
        window.open(AR, '_blank');
    }
})
```

Now all is working well about the xml file, I have a little problem with the window.open, which open my url but with %31 at the beggining, but it's another problem.

Thank you for your help !

Comment: Which line are you setting the breakpoint on?

Comment: Is that the actual error in the Chrome console? The screenshot looks more like your IDE. In fact it looks a lot like Visual Studio whose JS Intellisense is notoriously bad and should be ignored most of the time.

Comment: `url` is undefined because you have defined a **property** named `url` on an object and not a **variable** named `url` anywhere. This has nothing to do with your problem.

Comment: There is a pause at exception and yes it's in the Chrome console in the sources tab when we can see the variables. Quentin, I don't really understand. I've always used this way of ajax calling, how can I get my xml file so ?

Comment: @Rory i think it's just the dark mode of chromes dev tools. At least that'S how it looks for me as well, not VS

Comment: what happens in browser's console> network tab when this function is hit? and what happens in console window.. Look for error there. :) . BTW, it's a chrome console. I also use it with this color

Comment: When the function is hit, there is the allrtp.xml file in network I can see its content. But at the same time, I have `Uncaught ReferenceError: file is not defined` because I use file after the ajax called, which is supposed to be picked in the success function. This is not clear for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

file is undefined because you are declaring it inside a ajax success function

```
function openRecords(start, end) {
// Extraction of the xml file
 var file;
 $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'allrtp.xml',
    dataType: 'xml',
    success: function(xml) {
        file = $.parseXML(xml);
    },
    error: function(ex) {
        console.log(ex);
    }
})

// Test
var start = '2016-02-15T12:57:00+01:00';
var end = '2019-02-16T13:57:00+01:00';

setTimeout(function(){
// Editing the file to have the good dates
file.find('StartDateTime').text(start);
file.find('EndDateTime').text(end);},1500);

}
```

Comment: I edited the code to make the treatment in the success function, it works now !

Answer (score 0):

Add an error callback:
  error: function (ex) {}

Many things can be happening, you will get more info with the error callback. Probably you are querying an incorrect url. Do not trust that undefined upon url, see what returns your jquery ajax function. Maybe you should be querying something like '\files\xxx.xml'.

Comment: Ok I made a mistake and the problem isn't with the ajax part, I edit my first post.

Answer (score -1):

can you give me a picture of  Network in your broswer? I want to know the URL is send or not:
  1. F12 open your console
  2. select the Network tab 
  3. refresh the broswer
  4. check the request is send or not

Comment: I just checked and yes there is the allrtp.xml file. So I just understand even less... In the success function I have var file = $.parseXML(xml) but there is the exception file is undefined so why ?